# CodeDOM & .Net Modules

Tags: code-generation, codedom, runtime-compilation

How do I programmatically embed a .Net module to the assembly generated by CodeDOM?

Answer (score 1):

on VB

```
dim param as CompilerParameteres

param.EmbeddedResources.Add("dynamiclinklibrary")
```